# ForEach-Object - Trying to for loop each address in a variable

Tags: azure, powershell, loops, foreach

Back with another stupid question no doubt. I'm trying to perform a for loop for each IP Address present in the variable I create. I can create the string either comma or space separated, but either way I cannot get the for loop to do what I want.

I want each address in the list to be passed into this code block

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule match-condition add `
--match-variables RemoteAddr `
--operator IPMatch `
--values <ADDRESS_FROM_STRING>
```

I am building the list from this piece of script

```
$addressList = Invoke-WebRequest "https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt" -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
$threatList=(-split $addressList -join ',')
```

Here is my feeble attempt at this, which I gather is wrong, but I'm likely out of my depth here with my understanding of foreach and foreach-object.

```
$threatlist | ForEach-Object -process (az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule match-condition add `
--match-variables RemoteAddr `
--operator IPMatch `
--values $_)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: Use {} instead of ()

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen are you stalking me? ha! I get the following error using your suggestion, which is why I tried using a for loop to begin with.

program 'az.cmd' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt line:1

Comment: $threatlist will not be an array, so the foreach loop will only iterate once. Use $addressList.Split('here your delimiter')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out the pointers given by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) and [guiwhatsthat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5262941/guiwhatsthat):

- Use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) (whose built-in alias is `irm`), which directly returns the text of interest (which is a single string with IP addresses, each on its own line).
- Use the unary form of `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), to split the multi-line string into an *array* of tokens (by any run of whitespace, which in the case at hand means that each IP address becomes its own array element.
- Use the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet with the array as input, which processes each element in the [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) you pass to it, in which the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the input object (string, in this case) at hand.

```sh
-split (irm "https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt") |
  ForEach-Object {
    az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule match-condition add `
      --match-variables RemoteAddr `
      --operator IPMatch `
      --values $_
  }
```